# Reconstructing string of words using index position of words

Tags: python

I compressed a file and it gave each unique word in my string a value (0,1,2,3 etc)

I now have the list of numbers in order of appearance e.g (0,1,2,1,3,4,5,2,2 etc)

Using the numbers and list of unique words is there a way to decompress the sentence and get the original sentence I started with?

I have a text file with the following

[0,1,2,3,2,4,5,6,2,7,8,2,9,2,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19]
["Lines","long","lines","very","many","likes","for","i","love","how","amny","does","it","take","to","make","a","cricle..","big","questions"]

My code compressed the orignal sentence by getting the position and the unique words.

The original sentence was "Lines long lines very lines amny likes for lines i love lines how many lines does it take to make a cricle"

Now i want to be able to reconstruct the sentence using the list of unique words and position list. I want to be able to do this with any sentence not just this one example sentence.

Comment: how do you map numbers to words?

Comment: it'd be helpful if you could share the sample IO

Comment: Please, provide examples and data structures you are willing to use?

Answer (score 0):

To go back to words, you can access your map of words and for each of the numbers add a word onto the sentence.

```
numbers = [1, 2]
sentence = ""
words = {1: "hello", 2: "world"}
for number in numbers:
    sentence += words[number] + " "

sentence = sentence[:-1] # removes last space
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either a dict or a list and a comprehension with `str.join` :

```
words = ["I", "like", "boat", "sun", "forest", "dog"]
other_words = {0: "Okay", 1: "Example", 2: "...", 3: "$", 4:"*", 5: "/"}
sentence = (0,1,2,1,3,4,5,2,2)

print(" ".join(words[i] for i in sentence))
# I like boat like sun forest dog boat boat
print(" ".join(other_words[i] for i in sentence))
# Okay Example ... Example $ * / ... ...
```